# iPod: What does NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY mean? Is it safe to use a property like this on iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Inside the `CLLocation Class Reference` under the properties section this what it says for `coordinate`:

```
coordinate
The geographical coordinate information. (read-only)

@property(readonly, NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate
Discussion
When running in the simulator, Core Location assigns a fixed set of coordinate values to this property. You must run your application on an iOS-based device to get real location values.

Special Considerations
In iOS, this property is declared as nonatomic. In Mac OS X, it is declared as atomic.
```

I am just curious what this means: `@property(readonly, NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY)`.  Specifically the `NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY` part.  It seems to me that I can access this from an iPod touch.

Am I missing something?  Is it safe to use this from an iPod touch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreLocation is shared across both Mac OS X and iOS (née iPhone OS).

Here, `NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY` only means that the propriety is nonatomic on iOS and atomic on Mac OS X. The iPhone here is only referring to iOS, not iPhone vs iPod touch.

It is defined in TargetConditionals.h as this.

```
// Marks APIs whose iPhone versions are nonatomic, that is cannot be set/get from multiple threads safely without additional synchronization
#if !defined(NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY)
    #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    #define NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY nonatomic
    #else
    #define NS_NONATOMIC_IPHONEONLY
    #endif
#endif
```